# What is the name of this matrix operation?

Tags: matrices, vectors

I was reading [Vector Linear Independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) where I came across a matrix operation I have never seen before. What is this operation called and is it generally valid?
I mean there is a $2\times3$ matrix that was reduced to $2\times2$...!

> $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&\frac{16}{5}\\
> 0 & 1 & \frac 25\end{bmatrix}\left\{\begin{array}{c}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{array}\right\}=\left\{\begin{array}{c}0\\0\end{array}\right\}$$
>   We can now rearrange this equation to obtain
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\left\{\begin{array}{c}a_1\\a_2\end{array}\right\}=\left\{\begin{array}{c}a_1\\a_2\end{array}\right\}=-a_3\left\{\begin{array}{c}\frac{16}{5}\\\frac{2}{5}\end{array}\right\}$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd say that's just rearrangement, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: It's not reduced, it's just rewritten.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, correct, I now get it. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing special. We have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 16/5 \\
0 & 1 & 2 /5
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\a_2\\a_3
\end{bmatrix}
= \color{blue}{\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}\cdot a_1 +
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix} \cdot a_2} +
\begin{bmatrix}
16/5\\
2/5
\end{bmatrix}\cdot a_3
$$
and the blue part can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\a_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Coloring helped! Thank you for your effort.